# My renders come out blank

Tags: rendering

The Title says it all. Whenever I hit render, nothing comes out. Just a gray checkered screen. I didn't mess with the camera or render settings, and my other files render just fine, so I'm stumped.
The blend file is https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/GKX2pO3G

Comment: Fyi, all is rendered fine on my computer. So this is not about blender's settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked for me too. Try wait a little bit longer Eevee always shows this checker screen and once the render is finish the render will pop up done.
Fyi rendering your image with the settings you posted took me 1:30s with GPU NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060.